# Error when running azure-cli commands

Tags: node.js, azure

Today when I tried to create a deployment script using the azure nodejs sdk

```
azure site deploymentscript –-node
```

I got the following error:

```
    Mon Jul 14 2014 12:53:16 GMT-0400 (EDT):
[TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'imageDelete']
TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'imageDelete'
    at Object.exports.init (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/azure-cli/lib/commands/asm/vm._js:552:247)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/azure-cli/lib/cli.js:598:52
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at AzureCli._.extend.harvestPlugins (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/azure-cli/lib/cli.js:598:17)
    at new AzureCli (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/azure-cli/lib/cli.js:59:10)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/azure-cli/bin/azure.js:19:11)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
```

I tried uninstalling and reinstalling the azure-cli but it did not fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the error by editing /usr/local/lib/node_modules/azure-cli/lib/commands/asm/vm._js and adding a console.log at the end, just to see if it made it. After running azure again it was working.

I then removed the change and it is continuing to run correctly.